# Designing a controller using C software to control the pressure(bars) in a system using current(mA) of a proportionally opening valve

Tags: c, controller, software-design, control-theory, pid-controller

I want to design a PI controller in C code for controlling the system Pressure using the Current of a proportional solenoid valve. The valve is normally open, which lets the hydraulic fluid back to the tank, thus creating no pressure in the system (0 bars). If we increase the value of current, the valve starts getting proportionally closed, which in turn keeps increasing pressure. The current values of the valve increase from 0 to 2000mA.
If the target pressure setpoint for a certain functionality is 35 bars, the current needed to achieve this pressure value is 400mA. The controller should set the current to 400mA based on this pressure setpoint value and measure the actual value of pressure and the increase it to the desired target setpoint of 35 bars. It is difficult for me to understand how such a controller should be designed in software. Can someone please help me with the approach for implementing this?

According to my understanding, I think the code should have an error and an integral term. It should also have values for KI and KP:

Error = SetpointPressure – ActualPressure;
Integrator = Integrator + Ki * Error;

Comment: Thiswallofwordsisreallyhardtoreadcanyoubreakitupandaddsomecodeforcontext?

Comment: I have designed several very similar systems. However your question as it stands "how do I design my whole system" is too broad for this Q&A site. Instead you should be asking specific questions about specific issue you run into. Also, a big part in this project will be the hardware design, which is off-topic here on SO.

Comment: Where is your proportional and derivative part?

Comment: That being said, here are some things to consider. Specify an overall accuracy/resolution of the control function, early on before the PCB is designed. Specify any real-time and response parameters. Estimate where noise might appear in the control loop and how to counter it. Consider that most solenoids/valves need a start current applied before it even activates at all, so your control curve is unlikely 0mA to n mA, but rather x mA to y mA. It can probably be regarded as linear, but resistance in the circuit will vary _a lot_ depending on temperature.

Comment: The actual PI(D) part is one of the easier things to solve. There are other considerations such as if a "dither" frequency is required, how good the pressure sensors are and how linear they are (probably not very linear at all) - in my experience, they are always a big pain in the *** to work with and regulating valves based on pressure sensors is often not a good idea. You should considering regulating them based on current instead.

Comment: For eg. this is the code I tried to implement, but I am not sure if this is the right approach? Or is there something missing? Any suggestions??                             
          s16Current = 420;
   s16PressureSetpoint = 37; 
   s16Error = s16PressureSetpoint - s16ActualPressure;
   s16Integrator = s16Integrator + s16Ki * s16Error;
  s16Kp = 1;
  s16ActualPressure = s16Kp * s16Error + s16Integrator;

Comment: @SLovesToLearn Just google "fixed point PID controller". These are not all that difficult to implement programming-wise and you can grab example code off the net. Again, this is a minor problem - your biggest problem is that someone has decided to use some manner of pressure sensors hoping to get some meaningful control curve out of them. What's that decision based on and what are those sensors, is what you should be asking first of all.

Comment: @Lundin thankyou for your help. Can you suggest how can we decide minimum and maximum values for the integrator anti-windup? The codes I found for anti-windup directly suggests setting the integrator to these saturation values. But how can we determine these max and min saturation limits for changing control values for different pressures?

Comment: @SLovesToLearn In my experience you can just grab some "magic number" close to the maximum of the type, since the actual PI(D) calculation is probably using artificial units anyway. But again: someone has decided to replace all the camels of the desert caravan company with polar bears. The main concern then shouldn't be some detail regarding which scissors that are best for grooming polar bear fur. Rather, the question should be how it makes sense to use polar bears for desert caravans in the first place. Start with the bigger picture - will this system work at all? Why? Why not?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have all variables scaled in percentage (0-100%)

```
/*wt = setpoint  yt = process variable   ut = control action*/
ut = qPID_Control( &instance, wt, yt ); /* compute the control action */
/* action to the Final Control Element (FCE) should be inverse */
ut = 100.0f - ut;
```

just follow the same principle and scale the units according to your needs

you can use this C-code PID control library, is so robust and includes anti-windup and derivative filter https://github.com/kmilo17pet/qlibs

Comment: This code for anti-windup directly suggests setting the integrator to max and min saturation values. How can we determine these minimum and maximum values for the integrator anti-windup for changing values?

Comment: Saturation values depends of the physical restrictions of the Final Control Element (The actuator), in your particular case, the proportional solenoid valve. So for a valve, the control action should be between Min:0 and Max 100. e.g You can't tell a valve to open 150%, its impossible.